# First integral of $F''+2({\xi}F)' = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this question:

Deduce that the first integral of $F''+2({\xi}F)' = 0 $ is $F'+2{\xi}F = 0 $, when $F'(0)= 0$.

This is my work so far:

Let $F'$ be $G$,

$F''=G\frac{dG}{dF}$

$F''+2({\xi}F)' = F''+ 2F + 2{\xi}F'$

Substituting $F'$ and $F''$ gives: $G\frac{dG}{dF} = -2F - 2{\xi}G$

After this, I am not sure what to do with the $-2F$ in the above equation. If someone can help me walk through it. It'll be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange.com. Your general idea of using an auxiliary function such as $G$ is the right approach. You are running into trouble when you are deducing a formula that relates $F'$ and $G$. Remember that $F$ is a function of the independent  variable $\xi$. As an alternative approach, write the original differential equation as $(F' + 2 \xi F)'  = 0$  which suggests $G = F' + 2 \xi F$. Can you write down a differential equation for $G$? (It's very simple.) What does this imply for $G$?

Answer (score 2):

$$F'' + 2(\xi F)' = 0$$

Or, if you want to write that properly

$$F''(\xi) + 2(\xi F)'(\xi) = 0$$

Now integrate with respect to $\xi$ from $0$ to a generic point $t$

$$\int_0^t F''(\xi)d\xi + 2 \int_0^t (\xi F)'d\xi = F'(t) - F'(0) + 2(tF(t) - 0 \cdot F(0)) = F'(t) + 2tF(t) = 0$$

Or if you want to retain the original format just call $t = \xi$ to get 
$$F'(\xi) + 2\xi F(\xi) = 0$$